# Exception on custom form field not being propagated and form reposting for use of tupple

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-generic-views

I'm fairly new to python(3.5)/django(1.10), and I've run into the following problem:

I am using Django's generic CreateView to create a model and respective children model.

My objective is to save information about a purchase. A purchase is composed of a Bill and one or many Receipt. To accomplish this, I've created a custom Form (`BillForm`) with a custom field where user can input coma separated values that will be used to create receipts.

Here is what I have:

models.py

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    """ A given bill whenever an item is purchased."""
    number = models.CharField(_('Number'), max_length=20)
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Purchase Date'))
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, verbose_name=_('Company'),
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    ...

    def _get_receipts(self):
        ''' returns all receipts that related to a bill '''
        return Receipt.objects.filter(bill = self)
    receipts = property(_get_receipts)

class Receipt(models.Model):
    """ A receipt confirming a product is in our posession """
    number = models.CharField(_('Number'), max_length=20)
    bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill, verbose_name=_('Bill'),
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

urls.py:

```
    url(_(r'^create_purchase/$'), views.ObjectCreateView.as_view(
        model=Bill,
        form_class=BillForm
    ),
    name="create_purchase"),
```

forms.py:

```
class MultipleReceiptsField(forms.Field):
    ''' A custom field to store a list of coma separated receipts '''
    def to_python(self, value):
        ''' Normalize data to a set of receipts numbers '''
        if not value:
            return set()

        return set(v.strip() for v in value.split(',') if v.strip())

    def validate(self, value):
        ''' check if the values passed are less than 20 char long (limit for
        model). '''
        super(MultipleReceiptsField, self).validate(value)
        # had made the following a tuple, then updated to list and worked
        invalid_receipts = [r for r in value if len(r) > 20]

        if invalid_receipts:
            # EXCEPTION THROWN HERE BUT NOT PROPAGATED
            raise ValidationError(
                [ValidationError(_("Length of receipt %(r) is too large (max 20 characters)"),
                         code=INVALID_PARAMS, params={'r':int(r)}) # it was params={r:r} should have used 'r'
                for r in invalid_receipts]
            )

class BillForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ''' A form used to create a Purchase Bill. '''
    receipts = MultipleReceiptsField(label=_("Receipts"), widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' constructor used to filter the companies. '''
        # executes
        super(BillForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['company'].queryset =\ Company.objects.filter(is_provider=True).filter(is_active=True)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        ''' createe receipts when saving a bll '''
        # save logic | NEVER EXECUTES...
        # for each elementt in receipts, create a receipt object and
        # set its bill value to the bill that we just created
        bill = super(BillForm, self).save(commit=False)
        receipts_cd = self.cleaned_data["receipts"]

        ...

        return bill

    class Meta:
        model = Bill
        fields = ('company', "number", "currency", "price", "receipts")
```

view.py:

```
class ObjectCreateView(IsInPurchaseGroup, CreateView):
    model = None
    form_class = None
    #fields = "__all__"
    template_name = "purchases/object_form.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ObjectCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["title"] = str(ACTIONS[CREATE_ACTION]) + " " +\
            str(self.model._meta.verbose_name)
        context["button"] = ACTIONS[CREATE_ACTION]

        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        next_url, kwargs = get_next_url(self.request)

        if not next_url:
            # works because the pluralization of both models end with s
            next_url =\
                "purchases:{}s".format((str(self.model).split(".")[-1])[:-2])

            # if i am creating a bill, then i must navigate to
            # create_purchased_products in the warehouse department.
            if self.model == Bill:
                next_url = "warehouse:create_purchased_products"
                kwargs = {"receipts" : self.object.receipts}

        return reverse_lazy(next_url, kwargs=kwargs)
```

object_form.html

```
{% extends "purchases/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block body %}
<h3>{{ title }}</h3>

{% if error_message %}
<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>{{ form.as_table }}</table>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="Submit" value="{{ button }}"/>
    </div>
 </form>

{% endblock %}
```

#### The problem:

whenever a form_class is given on the url, the following functions don't get executed:

- BillForm.save()
- ObjectCreateView.get_success_url()

If I omit the form_class on the url and set variable `fields = "__all__"` (simply creating an object of my Bill model), then the method `ObjectCreateView.get_success_url()` gets called.

#### My question

Why the `BillForm.save()` nor the `ObjectCreateView.get_success_url()` don't get executed? I know there has to be something wrong with the `BillForm`, but I can't seem to understand what...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

#### Update

- Uploaded object_form.html and update forms.py
- There is no exception being thrown. After clicking on Submit, a POST gets sent to the server. On the client (the browser), no changes happen (form remains with already entered data).
- Found my errors; but I'm still unsure why it happens.

  - I had some exceptions being thrown in `MultipleReceiptsField.validate()`, but they didn't get propagated (when I submited the form, I didn't get exception, form just kept on posting).
  - After exception was fixed (saw that when placing invalid input will raise a validation error) and tried to submit with correct data, form kept on reposting.
  - Then I updated the `invalid_receipts` variable from being a tuple to a list and it began working

Am I missing some subtle difference between tuple and lists?

forms.py - not working:

```
class MultipleReceiptsField(forms.Field):
''' A custom field to store a list of coma separated receipts '''
def to_python(self, value):
    ''' Normalize data to a set of receipts numbers '''
    if not value:
        return set()

    return set(v.strip() for v in value.split(',') if v.strip())

def validate(self, value):
    ''' check if the values passed are less than 20 char long (limit for
    model). '''
    super(MultipleReceiptsField, self).validate(value)
    invalid_receipts = (r for r in value if len(r) > 20)

    if invalid_receipts:
        raise ValidationError(
            [ValidationError(_("Length of recipt %(r) is too large (max 20 characters)"),
                    code=INVALID_PARAMS, params={'r':int(r)})
            for r in invalid_receipts]
        )
```

forms.py - working:

```
lass MultipleReceiptsField(forms.Field):
''' A custom field to store a list of coma separated receipts '''
def to_python(self, value):
    ''' Normalize data to a set of receipts numbers '''
    if not value:
        return set()

    return set(v.strip() for v in value.split(',') if v.strip())

def validate(self, value):
    ''' check if the values passed are less than 20 char long (limit for
    model). '''
    super(MultipleReceiptsField, self).validate(value)
    invalid_receipts = [r for r in value if len(r) > 20]

    if invalid_receipts:
        raise ValidationError(
            [ValidationError(_("Length of receipt %(r) is too large (max 20 characters)"),
                    code=INVALID_PARAMS, params={'r':int(r)})
            for r in invalid_receipts]
        )
```

Comment: Presumably the form is not validating. Are you displaying errors on the template?

Comment: Are you seeing an error, such as an ImpropelryConfigured exception when the 'fields' attribute is commented?  That attribute must be provided in either the view or the model_form.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my question. I've updated with extra information.  @Daniel Roseman no errors, nor exceptions

Comment: @dashdrum it is commented because on the BillForm (the Meta) i provide fields. If you don't provide model_forms on urls.py, then you would need to uncomment fields in views.py. If you do so, then the Bill gets created. However, I wanted to use my BillForm because it provides the extra functionality that I needed

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in method save. Method save return instance of object. If cant save it return None. Your method return None all time. Create view check result of form save after call other methods. If it see none poccess aborted. You need return some instance or call super.save like this:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
        inst = super(BillForm, self).save(commit=False)
        #addition logic, all what you need.
        return inst
```

Or you need override valid method on your view class, without call super().valid() and override save method in form.

Sorry, my english very bad.

Comment: I updated the save method of the forms.py. My problem is that when I use the BillForm, the save method never gets executed. I even tried placing a `pring("HERE!!!")` right before the super call to see if i could see it in the output but nothing ... and no worries, english is not my first language either :)

Comment: Do you check returns of is_valid form method? Do you override valid method of CreateView to check its work?

Comment: the validate method should return None. If I'm not mistaken, the validation methods should raise a validation error on certain conditions. and after my update, the correct methods get executed.